# Emptying dispatch async queue - How does this code work?

Tags: ios, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

I'm making a asynchronous request call as shown below:

.h file:

```
@interface APIManager : NSObject {
    dispatch_queue_t dataQueue;
}
```

.m file:

```
-(id)init{
    dataQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.test.dataQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
}
```

This queue is used as below:

```
dispatch_async(dataQueue, ^(void){
    //data retrieval from server + parsing
});
```

When the user logs out, I'm emptying the queue as shown below:

```
-(void)logout{
    dispatch_async(dataQueue, ^{});
}
```

Am I doing it the right way? I don't want to suspend the queue and then resume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code in `logout` doesn't empty the queue, it just appends an empty block to the end of it.

Grand Central Dispatch doesn't have a cancellation function. You might want to look at using `NSOperationQueue`, which is just as easy to use, and *does* have a cancellation function.

Comment: GCD does have a cancellation function as of the latest version. However it is not clear that cancellation is what is wanted here, maybe the work in `dataQueue` actually needs to be done...

Answer (score 1):

Calling `dispatch_sync(dataQueue, ^{});` in `-logout` would allow you to know that all blocks submitted to the queue earlier have completed.

However it would not ensure that the queue is actually empty unless you ensure that nobody submits new blocks to `dataQueue` once `-logout` has been called (via separate synchronization presumably).

The usual technique to ensure that all related work has completed is to use a dispatch group associated to the queue, and submit all work to the queue with `dispatch_group_async()`. This allows you to wait for all the work in the group to complete with `dispatch_group_wait()` or to be notified when that happens via `dispatch_group_notify()` (e.g. to trigger some type of "asynchronous logout" if that makes sense).